# embedding live ip camera feed into webpage

Tags: embedding, ip-camera

i am trying to set up a few ip cameras for a client.

yet i am having trouble getting the stream from the camera to the webpage then for it to play through a player. i have tried different players such as WMP, VLC(cant get it to work). i am now trying to use jplayer which would be great if i could get it to work on this one as works for phones or so it says.

what i have done so far is to go into my router(thomson TG585 v8) and set up port forwarding.

i have set up port 554 on TCP/UDP which in the camera settings is the RTSP port.

i have set my camera to a static ip and am using no-ip for the ddns.

rtsp://thepolishedknob.servebeer.com/h264/1/media.amp

this is the url i am trying to use but i cannot get the stream on to the player i know the stream works outside my LAN as connected to it through VLC last night.

if anyone can help me it would be greatly appreciated as been working on this for over a week and been going nowhere.

so if you have noticed i have missed anything out or done something wrong please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

There is no universal way to do the embedding. Typically solution is one of the following:

- As IP cameras comes with web interface, they already provide some way to present video off the web page. Often, this is an ActiveX control based solution with respective browser limitations. You can check HTML and duplicate the code, and it can also be mentioned in the vendor's documentation.
- As you discovered the stream is `RTSP`, and hopefully valid `RTSP` without tricks, there might be a third party solution "player" to present the stream off the webpage.
- You might want to re-encode the stream into another format (VLC or another aplication), such as M-JPEG which is more browser friendly. You'll find a lot of discussions for this, e.g. http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=57715