# How to run multiple (4) LAN cameras in one screen

Tags: django, python-2.7, ip-camera

How to open my 4 LAN cameras live streaming (IP Ex: 192.168.2.111,192.168.2.112,192.168.2.113 and 192.168.2.114) in one django template page?

Comment: Could you answer how to open 1 camera?

Comment: I am not having 1 camera connection also

Comment: possible duplicate of [embedding live ip camera feed into webpage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820949/embedding-live-ip-camera-feed-into-webpage)